# How to get 'Q' at the beginning of every quarter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I do have the below code which gives me the quarter from my date column and is working fine.

**CODE**

```
order['Qtr'] = pd.to_datetime(order['Order Date']).dt.quarter
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

My requirement is i would like to add **Q** at the beginning of every quarter with the column name as **Quarter** . I want the output as below.

**Required Output**

[image]

Regards,

Bharath Vikas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is convert values to strings and prepend `Q`:

```
order['Quarter'] = 'Q' + pd.to_datetime(order['Order Date']).dt.quarter.astype(str)
```

Or convert values to quarter periods and then use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.strftime.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10, freq='170D')
order = pd.DataFrame({'Order Date': rng})  

order['Quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(order['Order Date']).dt.to_period('q').dt.strftime('Q%q')
print (order)
  Order Date Quarter
0 2017-04-03      Q2
1 2017-09-20      Q3
2 2018-03-09      Q1
3 2018-08-26      Q3
4 2019-02-12      Q1
5 2019-08-01      Q3
6 2020-01-18      Q1
7 2020-07-06      Q3
8 2020-12-23      Q4
9 2021-06-11      Q2
```

Comment: thanks for that, how to name column name as **Quarter** for this new quarter column?

Comment: @Vikas - Answer was edited, use `order['Quarter']` instead `order['Qtr']`

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be as follows:

```py
order['Quarter'] = "Q" + order["Qtr"].astype("str")
```

This basically casts your numeric values to string and concatenates them with `Q` in front of it.

Alternatively you can just map arbitrary conversion functions like so:

```py
order['Qtr'] = pd.to_datetime(order['Order Date']).dt.quarter
order['Quarter'] = df.map(lambda q: f"Q{q}")
```

Note that this uses F-strings which I believe requires python 3.6+